# In The Martian, why did NASA design the HAB to last only 31 days?

Tags: the-martian

At 17:11, Watney says that NASA designed the habitat to last for only 31 days on the surface of Mars.

Why did they not design something to last longer?

Comment: Because the mission was specifically limited to 31 sols (Mars days)

Comment: He also jokes about a ziplock bag costing $50,000 because... NASA. Consider payload weight, fuel, all the math. Every ounce comes at a cost. The hab may not have been designed to last exactly 31 days, but more like a range where 31 days is well within the safe zone. Maybe the next level would have added a whole ton of extra weight and cost substantially more for a mission with a strict budget, both in time and money

Comment: Because it would cost more, weigh more, and take longer to build.

Comment: Watney is a character with a strong tendency to dark humour and hyperbole. I don't think he'd mind exaggerating exactly how fragile the hub was to get his point (how low his chances of survival were) across.

Comment: It wasn't designed to last only 31 days, the books say they were supplied for 56 days, and the mission only lasted for 31.  Doesn't say anything about the hab only lasting 31 days

Comment: @CBredlow - From the book *"So that’s the situation. I’m stranded on Mars. I have no way to communicate with Hermes or Earth. Everyone thinks I’m dead. **I’m in a Hab designed to last thirty-one days."***

Answer (score 12):

This is explained slightly later in [the novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(Weir_novel)). The mission was only intended to last that long.

> ***The surface mission was supposed to be thirty-one days.*** For
>   redundancy, the supply probes had enough food to last the whole crew
>   fifty-six days. That way if one or two probes had problems, we’d still
>   have enough food to complete the mission.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Martian: Andy Weir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(Weir_novel))</sup></sub>

Assuming the NASA in the books operates in the same way that our own NASA do, they will have used [Reliability Engineering Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_engineering) to make sure that there is a near-zero-percent chance of a critical equipment failure (mission-affecting or life-affecting) occurring within those 31 days.

> ***NASA’s Reliability and Maintainability (R&M) program ensures that the
>   systems within NASA’s spaceflight programs and projects perform as
>   required throughout their life cycles to satisfy mission objectives.***
>   Mission objectives include safety, mission success and sustainability
>   criteria.
>
> <sub><sup>[NASA - Reliability and Maintainability Program](https://sma.nasa.gov/sma-disciplines/reliability-and-maintainability)</sup></sub>

Typically the best way to ensure that a piece of equipment has the lowest possible chance of breaking during its projected mission is to massively over-engineer it, hence why Mark has so much redundancy in his equipment and why most of his kit lasts years instead of weeks. Note, for example that he has multiple additional valves. They aren't likely to be needed, but scrubbing a multi-billion dollar mission for the want of a $2 valve isn't something that NASA would countenance.

> *Getting the tubing through the balloon canvas wasn’t too hard. I have
>   several spare valve patches. Basically they’re ten-by-ten-centimeter
>   patches of Hab canvas with a valve in the middle. **Why do I have these?
>   Consider what would happen on a normal mission if the regulator valve
>   broke. They’d have to scrub the whole mission. Easier to send spares.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Martian: Andy Weir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(Weir_novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: That doesn't indicate the Hab was designed to last only 31 days.

Comment: @Edlothiad That might depend on how you interpret "designed for". It could be seen as meaning "designed to last long enough for a 31 day mission". If part of that design includes overengineering it so that it has an expected lifespan of much more than 31 days, that could still be seen as being "designed to last 31 day". Or taken another way, it could be implied that it was designed to last **at least** 31 days.

Comment: @ToddWilcox that's all well and dandy, but that doesn't support the fact it was designed to last **only** 31 days.

Comment: @Edlothiad - The HAB was rated to last *at least* 31 days. Beyond that point the chances of it breaking go from near-zero to more-than-near-zero

Comment: @Edlothiad This is par for the course of NASA though, it's designed to work a short time, but greatly exceeds it's original mission.  The Voyager probes, and the Opportunity rover are good examples of this.

Comment: @CBredlow - If something has a near-zero chance of failure over 31 days, it probably contains bits that have a 50% chance of failure after decades of continual use.

Comment: @CBredlow Sure, there have been cases where they were designed to work for a short time. Opportunity's biggest challenge was the Solar Panels, and thats what was the hardest factor to reach the 90 day target, most everything else would work fine for far longer than 90 days (as is evident when its twin, Spirit, died). But this is a HAB, it would certainly have redundancies built in to last far longer that 31 days. Given The Martian was almost certainly inspired by Zubrin's *Mars Direct*, I will almost guarantee that it would've been designed to last far longer, while supplied

Comment: @Edlothiad so the hab isn't designed to be 'just 31 days', it's said in the movies and the novel that it has supplies for the crew to last 56 days.  It doesn't mean that the hab was only 31 days.  The mission was only 31 days.

Comment: @CBredlow so you're agreeing with me?

Comment: @Edlothiad I think I'm only disagreeing with your first comment, and  I think i've gotten lost in the comments.

Comment: @CBredlow My first comment is a fact. Valorum's post does not (explicitly) answer the question of "why it was designed to last **only** 31 days" Answer was it probably wasn't. His edits have done better to reflect that, but it's still not directly answered.